# Fibers Installed Failed. Meteor MUP Deployment Prepare Bundle: Failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, deployment, node-fibers, mup

I’m experimenting with the meteor platform, specifically deployment to EC2, I’m using the following a base https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-starter  -  I’m having no issues deploying other meteor projects, however with this project specifically, I am continuously being presented with “PREPARE BUNDLE: FAILED”. See below for details of environment, any help is greatly appreciated.

EC2 Details:

Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type 
t2.xlarge
CPUS: 4
MEMORY: 16gb

Security Groups & Key Pair are all fine… traffic is being allowed from required sources.

Terminal: MUP Setup

```
Started TaskList: Setup Docker
[ec2-18-234-99-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com] - Setup Docker
[ec2-18-234-99-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com] - Setup Docker: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Setup Meteor
[ec2-18-234-99-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com] - Setup Environment
[ec2-18-234-99-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com] - Setup Environment:         
SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Setup Mongo
[ec2-18-234-99-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com] - Setup Environment
[ec2-18-234-99-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com] - Setup Environment:     
SUCCESS
[ec2-18-234-99-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com] - Copying mongodb.conf
[ec2-18-234-99-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com] - Copying mongodb.conf: 
SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Start Mongo
[ec2-18-234-99-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com] - Start Mongo
[ec2-18-234-99-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com] - Start Mongo: SUCCESS
```

Terminal MUP Deploy:

```
Started TaskList: Pushing Meteor App
[ec2-18-234-99-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle 
to the Server
[ec2-18-234-99-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle 
to the Server: SUCCESS
[ec2-18-234-99-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com] - Prepare Bundle
[ec2-18-234-99-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com] x Prepare Bundle: FAILED

      ------------------------------------STDERR------------------------------------
      The command '/bin/sh -c cd  /built_app/programs/server &&     npm install --unsafe-perm' returned a non-zero code: 1

      ------------------------------------STDOUT------------------------------------
      ze);
                                                                                       ^
../src/fibers.cc:787:84: warning: 'bool v8::Object::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::AccessorGetterCallback, v8::AccessorSetterCallback, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::AccessControl, v8::PropertyAttribute)' is deprecated (declared at /root/.node-gyp/8.4.0/include/node/v8.h:3120): Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    fn->SetAccessor(uni::NewLatin1Symbol(isolate, "fibersCreated"), GetFibersCreated);
                                                                                    ^
../src/fibers.cc: In instantiation of 'void uni::MakeWeak(v8::Isolate*, v8::Persistent<T>&, P*) [with void (* F)(void*) = Fiber::WeakCallback; T = v8::Object; P = void]':
../src/fibers.cc:341:60:   required from here
../src/fibers.cc:55:3: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::Persistent<v8::Object>::SetWeak(void*&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
   handle.SetWeak(val, WeakCallbackShim<F>);
   ^
../src/fibers.cc:55:3: note: candidates are:
In file included from /root/.node-gyp/8.4.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../src/coroutine.h:1,
                 from ../src/fibers.cc:1:
/root/.node-gyp/8.4.0/include/node/v8.h:544:18: note: template<class P> void v8::PersistentBase<T>::SetWeak(P*, typename v8::WeakCallbackInfo<P>::Callback, v8::WeakCallbackType) [with P = P; T = v8::Object]
   V8_INLINE void SetWeak(P* parameter,
                  ^
/root/.node-gyp/8.4.0/include/node/v8.h:544:18: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../src/fibers.cc:55:3: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
   handle.SetWeak(val, WeakCallbackShim<F>);
   ^
In file included from /root/.node-gyp/8.4.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from ../src/coroutine.h:1,
                 from ../src/fibers.cc:1:
/root/.node-gyp/8.4.0/include/node/v8.h:555:18: note: void v8::PersistentBase<T>::SetWeak() [with T = v8::Object]
   V8_INLINE void SetWeak();
                  ^
/root/.node-gyp/8.4.0/include/node/v8.h:555:18: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o] Error 1
fibers.target.mk:102: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o' failed
make: Leaving directory '/built_app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/opt/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1065-aws
gyp ERR! command "/opt/nodejs/bin/node" "/opt/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /built_app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v8.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed
sh: 1: nodejs: not found
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No license field.

npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! fibers@1.0.8 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.8 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-09-19T15_39_09_837Z-debug.log
```

SOLVED:

```
docker: {
  image: 'meteorhacks/meteord:base',
}
```

My version of node was not supported by the project's meteor version.

Comment: What does `meteor node -v` return in your local development project? Your node gyp builds the native fibers against 8.4.0, do the versions match?

Comment: Hi, node is version 0.10.4 and I'm running METEOR@1.3

Comment: Solved. For anyone having the same issue. See my edited post above.